# Flow Run Continues Even Without Permission

Tags: visual-workflow, package, custom-permission

I am testing my package which includes a flow that is restricted with the users with particular custom permission and this restriction is applied inside of the Decision element of the flow (like in the example below)

[image][image]

However when I install the package for admin user and test the flow, even though admin doesnt have that custom permission, flow still passes Yes from Decision element. Does anyone have idea why this happens ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: When installing the app if you use "For Admins" or "For All Users" the custom permission is automatically added to the relevant profile(s), which would be why the flow behaves like the admin has permission (because they do). This updating of standard/all/select profiles is, IMHO, an anti-pattern for any package with even moderate complexity. Salesforce needs to provide an option to not update any profiles and make this the default.

Comment: Hi Phil and thanks for the info, do you know any workaround to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

When installing the managed package, if you use one of the "For Admins" or "For All Users" options, the custom permission is automatically added to the relevant profile(s). This will be why the flow behaves like the admin has permission (because they do).

To resolve this, install for select profiles and select a profile you don't care about (I'm not sure you can do this and select no profiles, but give it a try).

<opinion>This updating of standard/all/select profiles is, IMHO, an anti-pattern for any package with even moderate complexity. Salesforce needs to provide an option to not update any profiles and make this the default.</opinion>

Comment: +1 for the imho; especially as we move to permission-less Profiles. Package should include a PS that admin can assign to themselves to do post-install config (speaking as a org admin, not as an ISV dev)

Comment: As I tested it installs the package anyway for the system admin (no unselecting available) and even if the custom permission is not assigned to the admin user, flow still runs, so in this stage, there is no way to restrict the admin user from the flow per my efforts, except deactivating the flow

Comment: I thought you were trying to ensure the admin did not have the custom permission, not the ability to run the flow...? Have you tried updating the System Administration profile after install to remove the custom permission from it?